# can nginx proxy pass to url with mutiple subdomains?

Tags: nginx

I have a website https://something.something.example.com:443 which happily resolves in a browser correctly. However when I try to access it via the nginx reverse proxy. Nginx appears to proxy pass to https://something.example.com:443 even though the location is set to `proxy_pass https://something.something.example.com:443;`. Is nginx basically not capable of what I'm trying to do or is just most likely something wrong with my config.
Thanks

Comment: How did you find out where nginX proxy passes to? Was it from the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I am for a lack of better words your typical programmer. There is not any valid reason why nginx would not support subsub-domains. The issue was with a upstream server. After that issue was resolved, I was able to get nginx to proxy pass to a server with a subsubdomain.

TL;DR
Yes nginx can proxy pass to subsub-domains (subsub.sub.example.com) if you didn't already know.